IPv6 clients only ask for DHCPv6 addresses on FE80
Why would IPv6 clients only ask for DHCPv6 addresses on FE80:: (link-local unicast)?  Autoconfigured addresses are fine (on 2001:4341:360:65::/64 as expected).
Have I screwed up my radvd.conf (below; that's not the real /64.)?
interface lo
{
        AdvSendAdvert on;
};

interface eth0
{
        AdvSendAdvert on;
        AdvManagedFlag on;
        AdvOtherConfigFlag on;
        AdvLinkMTU 1280;

        AdvRASrcAddress {
                2001:4341:360:65:53:53:53:53;
        };

        prefix 2001:4341:360:65::/64
        {
                AdvOnLink on;
                AdvRouterAddr on;
        };

};


Are you asking why the DHCPv6 specification (RFC 8415) says DHCPv6 clients may use an IPv6 link-local address as their source address when sending DHCPv6 packets?

Sending the IPv6 link-local address doesn't surprise me, but the Kea DHCP6 server only handing out only LL addresses in response is a problem.
(I've got a lovely table of addresses on 2001:4341:360:65::/64, but kea DHCP6 server refuses to hand them out; I had to add a LL pool to make stop it whining of no addresses available.)

If your problem is with Kea, why haven't you discussed your Kea config?

I don't know what it is. I'll add the kea config.
